# CSS opacity box not show the text exactly

Tags: css, wordpress

I try to making a picture information box on wordpress blog.I want to information box show a bit transparent.I have no problem with that.But text get transparent to when I do that.

I use this code in article.

```
<div class="resimKapsayici">
<img src="http://www.domascal.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/valentina-tereskova-domascal.pg" width="728" height="728" />

<p class="resimaltbg" style="color: #fff;">
<b>Dr Valentina Tereshkova, the first woman in space, realised she did not have her toothbrush upon reaching orbit. &nbsp;&nbsp;</b></p>


</div>
<style>
.resimKapsayici {position:relative}
.gercekyazi {position:absolute;left:0px;top:412px;}
.resimaltbg {

    margin: 90px;
  margin-top:-64px;
  background-color: #4286f4;
  border: 0px solid black;
  opacity: 0.8;
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);}




.resimaltbg p{
opacity:1;
}

</style>
```

What I tried untill now ?

```
<p class="resimaltbg" style="color: #fff;" "opacity: 1;>
<b>Dr Valentina Tereshkova, the first woman in space, realised she did not have her toothbrush upon reaching orbit. &nbsp;&nbsp;</b></p>
```

But it's not work.I don't want to text transparent.How I can do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following to the .resimaltbg class:

```
rgba(66,134,244,0.8);
```

And then remove the opacity and filter properties.

This sets the alpha transparency only on the background and doesn't affect the content within it. When you try to do this by using opacity it will always affect all of the content with the element.

PS Your inline style attribute:

```
<p class="resimaltbg" style="color: #fff;" "opacity: 1;>
```

has a syntax error with the quotations marks. It should be:

```
<p class="resimaltbg" style="color: #fff; opacity: 1;">
```

Comment: I don't use rgba just edit class code and it's work.Thank you.

Comment: @dukedeivil294 Background appear a second and then gone !!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Did you make all the changes I outlined? And you're seeing the background for a second and then it disappears? Do you still see the text inside the p?

Comment: What I need to do ?

Comment: You have some weird positioning stuff going on with that <p> but the easy fix for it is to add position: relative; and z-index: 100; to the .resimaltbg class. Also, it didn't look like you updated the background color property with what was in my answer so you won't see the opacity effect until you do that.

Comment: I did now  background-color: rgba(66,134,244,0.8); 
it work now thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can just make the background have opacity, instead of the whole element:

Turn the color into RGB (#4286f4 = rgb(66, 134, 244)) and then use `background-color: rgba(66, 134, 244, a);` where a is a number between 0 and 1 (Opacity)

Answer (score 1):

For class `resimaltbg` add `background-color: rgba(66, 134, 244, 0.8)` and `color:#fff`